# Expected number of tables that contain both male and female.

Tags: statistics

If you have 15 women and 15 men at a party, given that there are 15 available tables, what is the expected number of tables which will contain both a man and a woman. Note: Each table can contain an unlimited amount of people.

Comment: Does each person have to sit down?

Comment: @JonathanDavidson yes they do.

Comment: You need to make some assumption about how seats are chosen.  Otherwise all sorts of scenarios are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch of proof: Let $X_i$ be the random variable which is $1$ if there is at least one woman and one man at table $i$, and $0$ otherwise. The variable you want the expectation of is
$$
X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{15}
$$
Now remember that expectation is linear.

Comment: What about the men?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I missed that in the question. Easily fixed. Still, my main point, that you can focus on a single table and not worry about interactions, stands.

Comment: And why should $E(X_j)$ all be the same?

Comment: Maybe Table $1$ is the only one with a good view of the football game, so all the men will sit there.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Doesn't matter. Expectation is linear even with dependent, differently-distributed variables. You just have to calculate $E(X_1)$ on its own, so the answer is not $15E(X_1)$, but $E(X_1)+14E(X_2)$. What I said in my answer still stands, and is, in my opinion, the easiest route to the answer by a wide margin even if all the tables were different, and even if some people wanted to sit together or apart.

Comment: @Arthur so would you simply do 15*$\sum_{i=1}^{15} E[X_i]$

Comment: @Math2Hard That's $15$ times too large. You're already summing all the fifteen expectations, there is no need to multiply by fifteen again. It's just that if all the expectations are the same, that sum is the same as $15\cdot E(X_1)$.